# leer nombre de archivo excel

Tags: c#

Me gustaría saber como cortar el nombre de un archivo excel, ya que mi intención es tomar solo unos números.

Me explico, mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
string thisfile2 = openFileDialog1.FileNames[i - 1];
```

donde `thisfile2` contiene la nomenclatura de `12345ESRDI001-A`
y solo quiero que tome el valor de `001`
pero la `I` no me toma, el `-` si pero no la `I`,

```
char deli = 'I';
string[] n1 = A.Split(deli);
string x = n1[1];
char deli2 = '-';
string[] x2 = x.Split(deli2);
string x3 = x2[0];
```

espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Usando el código que nos muestras, con un valor de entrada de `12345ESRDI001-A`, en `x3` el resultado es `001`. No es lo que buscas?

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que siempre quieres los tres numeros antes del guion tu funcion es:

```
     var input = "12345ESRDI001-A";
    var pos = input.IndexOf('-');

    var nombreNumero = input.Substring(pos - 3, 3);
```

saludos.